# mobile responsive css - image not rescaling

Tags: html, css

So I have website and at the footer, where I’m using a image(background) as footer.
On mobile looks gross.

But I can’t figure out why. It’s not rescaling & and the image quality is real bad on mobile.
The code is:

```
footer {
padding: 50px 0 30px;
background: url(“../img/bg-footer.jpg”) center center no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

```
.bg-footer {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
top: -100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 0;
overflow: hidden;
border-radius: 30px;
-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;
-ms-border-radius: 30px;
-o-border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```
.bg-footer img {
margin-left: -300px;
}
```

the web: http://petofi.vac.hu/proba23/

Comment: You could try `background-size: 100%`, but the image is much wider than the element on mobile. I'd consider modifying the image itself and putting the src of the modified option for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cleverly faded the bg to black all around your edges, you can easily have the background float smaller than your element. Use 'contain' for your background size.

CSS

```
footer {
  padding: 50px 0 30px;
  background: url(“../img/bg-footer.jpg”) 50% 50% / contain no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help first, but like this on mobile completely moves up from the bottom

Comment: In that case, you use ```bottom``` instead of the second ```50%``` so when it sizes down the bottom stays snug to it's container's bottom.

Comment: so you mean like bottom: 50%; if yes, its still stays upper

Comment: Like this: ```background: url(“../img/bg-footer.jpg”) 50% bottom / contain no-repeat;```.